# Alternatives to allclient jar?

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

So, I'm trying to find out if there is an alternative to the IBM MQ allclient jar. I have an application that needs to act as a client to IBM MQ. Adding this to dependencies stanza of gradle like so...

`dependencies {
    implementation 'com.ibm.mq:mq-jms-spring-boot-starter:2.0.9'
...`

results in a jar that is 8M. The application works, but I was wondering if there are any smaller jar(s) that supply what I need without being so large. I'm trying to make the smallest image possible, and this jar is the largest in the application:

`7.9M Jan 10  2019 com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.1.0.0.jar`

Comment: I suppose you could extract the jar and pull out all the classes that you do not reference or are not referenced as a dependency and then package it back as a jar, but I'm sure this would be unsupported by IBM and is probably not recommended.  In today's environments if you are worried about 8MB you may have bigger problems :).  There is also the option to use other APIs to connect to MQ.  Current versions of MQ support MQTT and AMQP for Pub/Sub as well as a REST (http) call to be able to do simple put/get operations. Note MQTT requires MQ Advanced on the queue manager end.

Comment: What is wrong with using allclient?  The JVM will only load the classes that your applications is using and not all of the classes in the JAR file.

Comment: The reason I'm looking to slim this down is to create a smaller container image. I was looking at how to reduce the size of our application and this jar was the very largest.